# Python - Split inconsistent columns in a text file with inconsistent spacing and sparse data

Tags: python, parsing, formatting, text-parsing

I have a text file which is an OCRed bank statement which I am processing using Python 2.7. I currently extract the bank name, account details and list of transactions. The list of transactions is currently stored in a list of lists with each line in the statement being a single entry in the list of lists preserving white spaces, as such:

```
[[' 01 Apr 16      DD     FAKE DESCRIPTION1                 24.20                              1,157.78           '], 
[' 02 Apr 16      ATM    FAKE DESCRIPTION2                                                                       '], 
['                       FAKE DESCRIPTION2                 50.00                              1,107.78           '],
etc...]
```

A sample text file is available here -> [Text file preserving white spaces](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21471588/Text.txt). ALL WHITE SPACES ARE WHITE SPACES NOT TABS.)

As you can see from the file there is some structure to the data where in all there are 6 columns, although not every one of them is populated.
My objective is to create a list of transactions sorted by transaction type (second column) or whether the transaction is a debit or credit (columns 4 or 5), however a single transaction can span multiple lines.

I have searched the forums and documentation of various libraries but cannot find a reliable way of achieving this. At this stage the sorting is not important. I am looking for ways to consistently create rows of data which I can later process.

Therefore, the desired output should look something like this (Note the empty 5th column as these are debit transactions):

```
[['01 Apr 16', 'DD', 'FAKE DESCRIPTION1', '24.20', '','1,157.78']
['02 Apr 16', 'ATM', 'FAKE DESCRIPTION2 FAKE DESCRIPTION2', '50.00', '', '1,107.78']
['04 Apr 16', ')))', 'FAKE DESCRIPTION3 FAKE DESCRIPTION3', '8.60', '', '1,099.18']
etc...]
```

I tried using `re.split(r'\s{2,}',tr[0])` and `re.split(r'(\s+)', tr[0])` but they do not provide the desired output. I also tried:

```
regex = r'^(.+)\b\s{2,}\b(.+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(.+)\s+(\d+)'
for line in s.splitlines():
    lst = [i.strip() for j in re.findall(regex, line) for i in j if j]
    print(lst)
```

...as suggested here -> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874117/how-to-strip-variable-spaces-in-each-line-of-a-text-file-based-on-special-condit), but still no luck.

Any ideas whether there is a library that can do such a thing or some simple code which can get me closer to a solution. I'm very new at Python but in love with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you identify the transactions that are split over several lines?  If so, a first pass through the data to reduce every transaction to a single line may be a helpful first step.  After that, parsing the line with regexes, as you are doing, may be more successful.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @rd_nielsen. Yes, I can isolate each transaction by the second column (transaction type) as this is consistently present at the start of every transaction. I'll give it a try and post the outcome.

Comment: To my eyes, this looks a lot more like something you should parse with a fixed-width format reader.  Do you have a lot like this file?  The only problem is the change in indentation at the end of 19 Apr, but if there's only this file we can do that manually, or if we know that there's always going to be one right shift we can look for it.

Comment: Thanks @DSM, currently I only have around 20 files like this. This is just a portion of a whole statement and the indentation is present in all statements that span multiple sheets. This is just a proof-of-concept but will need to process around 5000 documents from different banks by the end of it. Although the formats are similar they may have slight variations, however column 2 (type) seems to be the key. I can reliably detect the bank it is coming from so writing parsing code for every bank wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @PDF417: as I see it, the challenge will be column #5 (the 700.00).  I can't see a way to distinguish it from the other two columns syntactically without using its positional information (although I guess you could use the meaning of the columns to rule certain options out), which led me to think that FWF is going to be a better approach.  But you're probably going to have to do semantically-aware validation after the fact anyhow, so it might not be such a bad idea to use it for disambiguation.

Comment: @rd_nielsen, I can confirm that I am able to identify individual transactions where the result is something like this: 02 Apr 16 ATM FAKE DESCRIPTION2 FAKE DESCRIPTION2 50.00 1,107.78 --- 04 Apr 16 ))) FAKE DESCRIPTION3 FAKE DESCRIPTION3 8.60 1,099.18 --- 08 Apr 16 VIS FAKE DESCRIPTION4 FAKE DESCRIPTION4 8.95 1,090.23 --- 11 Apr 16 DD FAKE DESCRIPTION5 191.38 --- ))) FAKE DESCRIPTION6 FAKE DESCRIPTION6 7.10 1,891.75 --- etc... However this messes up the column structure so I think I'd better go down the route of FWF as DSM suggested.... Any other thoughts?

Comment: The column widths change at line 35 in your example data file, so it appears to me that parsing entirely as FWF would have to be able to adapt to these changes.  Perhaps you could use regexes to identify the first three columns and then use FWF to parse the remainder of the line.